# Add Custom python.pythonPath to List of Interpreters

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythonpath, vscode-python

I want to use a custom python interpreter, which you can do by adding to `python.pythonPath`, as seen in the image below.
However, I thought that there would be an option so that I could add an interpreter to the list of available interpreters that you can see in the below, so that I can easily switch between them, without the need to go rooting around in my user/workspace/folder settings.

Is there any way to add to the list as opposed to using `python.pythonPath` to override what is currently shown in the bottom left?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing and reopening vscode the interpreter is now shown.

Answer (score 1):

The extension [searches in certain places for interpreters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) like `PATH` and in places where you say to look for virtual environments. If you can get your interpreter to show up in one of those places then it will show up in the list. Otherwise what you're asking for isn't currently available (although you could open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python if you want).

Comment: Thanks Brett. I added the feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8240

Comment: I updated the feature request as it seems to be a refresh issue with the interpreter list.